# animation is`t working in the pseudo element

Tags: html, css

Here is my code, I want to make an underscore when hovering over input.

```css
.form_field_container::after {
  content          : "";
  position         : absolute;
  bottom           : -2px;
  height           : 2px;
  background-color : red;
  left             : 0;
  transition       : all 10s;
  width            : 10px;
  }
.form_input:hover .form_field_container::after {
  width : 100%;
  }
```

If you do `after` when hovering over the element itself, which you need to emphasize, `.form_field_container:hover::after{}`. then everything works, but if you do `form_input:hover .form_field_container::after`, then for some reason the property stops being applied

```HTML
<div class="form_field_container" style="margin-bottom: 22px">
  <span class="enter_label">Логин</span>
  <input
    type="text" 
    placeholder="Введите ваш логин или электронную почту" 
    name="login" 
    class="form_input login_input">
</div>
```

Comment: `.form_field_container` is not a child of `.form_input`

Comment: @MisterJojo, What do I need to do to make it work?